# How JLS corresponds to Sun javac / why they do not match

Tags: java, javac, jls

In Java given this:

```
String a = "str";
CharSequence b = "charseq";
```

you can write

```
b = b + a;
```

but cannot write (gives a compiler error)

```
b += a;
```

The error is

```
incompatible types
found   : java.lang.CharSequence
required: java.lang.String
```

Now in JLS Second Edition this was explainable by this line in [15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/java_langspec_2.0_html/expressions.doc.html#5304):

`All compound assignment operators require both operands to be of primitive type, except for +=, which allows the right-hand operand to be of any type if the left-hand operand is of type String.`

But in JLS Third Edition this comment disappeared, the only thing that is said about compound operator is at [15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

`A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.`

which doesn't seem to work (see above).

So my question is - what exactly is the relationship between javac and JLS and is this particular example an error in javac or an error in JLS?

Comment: In essence, you answered your own question:

`All compound assignment operators require both operands to be of primitive type, except for +=, which allows the right-hand operand to be of any type if the left-hand operand is of type String.`

Note that you're left-hand operand IS NOT of type String

Comment: Yes, but he stated that in JLSv3 that comment changed, and now a cast is performed. Despite it being declared CharSequence, the actual implementation is a string, so if the comment in JLSv3 is correct, it should cast it and work properly.

Comment: It appears that the javac with which you are testing complies with JLSv2 and not JLSv3.

Comment: 2 DwB - right, that's why i got this qn - what is the relationship between javac and JLS. It seems that javac from jdk6 should comply with JLSv3, but apparently it doesn't

Comment: It looks like either the compiler has a bug here - their developers didn't see that the specification changed here. (By the way, the same should occur with `Object` instead of `CharSequence`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*compiler error* is a bug in your version javac. As [pointed in prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320546/how-jls-corresponds-to-sun-javac-why-they-do-not-match/7325674#7325674) this bug is fixed in Java 7.

See eg [Bug ID 7058838](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7058838) at Sun bug database:

- description:

> A following function cannot be compiled in java 1.6 or less,. but it can be compiled in java 1.7.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Object x = "x";
           String y = "y";
           x += i;
    }
```

- state:
  **Not a Defect**
- evaluation:

  > For an Object x and a String y, x+=y is just x=(Object)(x+y). Since y is a String, x undergoes string conversion to produce a string which is concatenated with y, before the no-op cast to Object. The JLS has not changed in this area between SE 6 and SE 7; the program should have been legal for many years.

---

For a background, see also old [Bug Id 4741726](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4741726)

- description:

> javac used to allow expressions of the form `o += s` where o is a variable of type Object and s is an expression of type String. We fixed that recently (4642850) and this caused a build failure (4741702). Perhaps this is common enough that we should relax the spec instead of fixing the compiler?

- Category:
  java:compiler
- Release Fixed:
  **7(b25)** - as far as I understand, this means fixed in build 25 of Java 7
- evaluation:

> I'm inclined to relax the spec, though we'd have to know what other implementations do before making a final call on this.
> 2002-09-04
> JLS3 permits Object+=String because the '+' means string concatenation and that is able to concatenate an Object with a String as easily as a String with an Object.
> 2008-01-31

Comment: Thanks for looking up the bug Ids here (I couldn't find them).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann yeah. In this case, JLS section id was the key. I googled for `site:bugs.sun.com "15.26.2"`. Bugs revealed with this weren't most relevant ones but hopping through `Related Bugs` links eventually led me to 7058838 and 4741726

Answer (score 2):

should be a javac bug then.

compiles fine in javac 7. so somebody reported it and it's fixed.

Comment: +1 for testing this. (Though isn't there a JLS rewrite in the work, i.e. won't we get a JLS 4 soon?)

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you answered your own question:

`All compound assignment operators require both operands to be of primitive type, except for +=, which allows the right-hand operand to be of any type if the left-hand operand is of type String.`

Note that you're left-hand operand IS NOT of type String

Comment: that comment is from JLSv2 while javac from java 6 seems to be built upon JLSv3, thus the qn